How can I abort the ncdu disk scan and browse via the ncdu the files and folders that it has been able to scan so far?
By default, if one aborts the ncdu disk scan via the keyboard shortcut Q, it returns to the terminal.
How can I abort the ncdu disk scan and browse via the ncdu the files and folders that it has been able to scan so far?

Example of ncdu scanning some disk:




  ┌───Scanning...──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │                                                                                                                            │
  │ Total items: 265013   size: 329.2 GiB                                                                                      │
  │ Current item: /home/dernoncourt/files/x/M/test14984.txt                                                                    │
  │                                                                                                                            │
  │                                                                                                                            │
  │                                                                                                                            │
  │                                                                                                                            │
  │    Scanning...                                                                                            Press q to abort │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘






Do you have reason to think this is possible? I don't know that it isn't, but it would be very strange if the program were written in such a way as to allow it to prepare output before it knows what kind of output to display, and since this needs to descend into subdirectories and doesn't print output as it goes, I would be very surprised if what you want is possible. Why not just use du instead?

@terdon could still show an incomplete listing. I'd like do be able to browse folders.

I usually refrain from giving "no" answers, as lots of things can usually somehow be done, however; I've tried a few things, and it appears that this can't be reasonably done (and by reasonably I mean: without changing ncdu's source code and recompiling it so that it wouldn't leave a malformed output file as-is on premature exit, which is something it unfortunately does).
There's an -o option which can tell ncdu to output the scanned data to a file (and an -f option that can tell it to import scanned data from a file), however unfortunately both quitting ncdu "normally" by hitting Q and signaling ncdu with all signals from 0 to 30 while it's running result in ncdu producing a broken JSON as the output file (which of course generates errors if read back into ncdu using -f).
I've ran the following command to test ncdu's reaction to all signals from 1 to 30:
for sig in {1..30}; do
    printf 'Attempting -%d\n\n' "$sig"
    ncdu -0 / -o out &
    sleep 0.2
    kill -${sig} $!
    ncdu -0 -f out
    sleep 3
    printf '\n'
done >results 2>&1

Basically this started ncdu at each iteration, telling it to scan for / and waiting for a fifth of a second before proceeding to signal it with a signal in the range 1-30, immediately trying to read the output file back into ncdu.
Here are the results:
Attempting -1

Line 169288 byte 10: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -2

Line 174721 byte 9: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -3

Line 166148 byte 2: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -4

Line 181390 byte 0: Expected JSON object.

Attempting -5

Line 165969 byte 18: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -6

Line 173376 byte 16: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -7

Line 176738 byte 14: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -8

Line 175214 byte 19: Expected ',' or '}'.

Attempting -9

Line 175214 byte 19: Expected ',' or '}'.

Attempting -10

Line 169088 byte 22: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -11

Line 159768 byte 8: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -12

Line 168863 byte 36: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -13

Line 177564 byte 7: Expected ':'.

Attempting -14

Line 167712 byte 50: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -15

Line 169088 byte 22: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -16

Line 169564 byte 50: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -17

Line 205699 byte 21: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -18

Line 181390 byte 0: Expected JSON object.

Attempting -19

Line 168941 byte 17: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -20

Line 176914 byte 24: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -21

Line 172923 byte 27: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -22

Line 170584 byte 74: Expected ':'.

Attempting -23

Line 176914 byte 24: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -24

Line 168178 byte 34: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -25

Line 176367 byte 34: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -26

Line 177996 byte 33: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -27

Line 170584 byte 74: Expected ':'.

Attempting -28

Line 184858 byte 5: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -29

Line 174458 byte 26: Unexpected EOF.

Attempting -30

Line 166576 byte 54: Expected JSON object.

So what your left with is having ncdu stop whichever way you prefer (I suppose using Q would be the most convenient) and trying to repair the broken JSON.
jq --seq doesn't help in this case, but there are many node modules claiming to be able to fix broken JSONs, so you may try your luck with one of those (or, if you feel confident enough they won't steal your filesystem's data, with one of the many online services that advertise being able to do this).
